# Transaction fees withdraw/deposit in

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, weight, fee

I made transactions on a simple EVM DEX contract.

I initially called the `approve` method which only triggered `balances.withdraw` event. I understand that this event is triggered as calling this write-method requires transaction fees.
[image: Events from calling approve method]

I then triggered the `addLiquidity` method on the contract which is payable and thus should receive the `native token` while this method is executed. While executing this transaction, I see that there are both `balances.withdraw` and `balances.deposit`. I don't understand why it didn't just withdraw
all the required transaction fee at once, instead of withdrawing a larger portion and then depositing back some later on.
[image: Events from calling addLiquidity method]

What is the cause for this?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how the balances pallet handles taking funds for gas vs taking funds THEN giving them to another account - your contract in this case.

When you deploy a contract you will see even more events related to balances where an account is created, funded with the storage deposit, etc, etc.